# Distribution of a Poisson with an Exponentially-distributed rate

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X|Y=\lambda \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $Y \sim \operatorname{Exp}(1)$. How I can find the distribution of $X$?

It is true that $\mathbb{P}(X = t|Y=\lambda) = \frac{\mathbb{P}(X=t, Y=\lambda)}{\mathbb{P}(Y=\lambda)}$.

But I don't know if X and Y are independent or not. How can I proceed next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
    \mathbb{P}(X = k) = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{P}(X = k \vert Y)]
$$
Since $X \vert Y = \lambda \sim \mathcal{P}(\lambda)$,
$$
     \mathbb{P}(X = k \vert Y) = \dfrac{e^{-Y}Y^k}{k!}
$$
The only thing left to do is to calculate
$$
    \mathbb{E}(e^{-Y}Y^k) = \int_0^\infty e^{-2t}t^kdt
$$

Comment: Oh. So $X|Y=\lambda \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ don't mean that $\lambda$ is fixed? So I have $X|Y=\lambda_1 \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_1)$, $ X | Y= \lambda_2 \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda_2) $ for $\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2$ ?

Comment: So it will give that $X \sim Geom(\frac{1}{2})$.

Comment: @MathLearner Yes, when write $X \vert Y = \lambda \sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda)$, it means that the Poisson distribution depends on a particular value of $Y$